# $\lim_{z\to1}\frac{1-z^*}{1-z}$ using Wolfram Alpha

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, wolfram-alpha

I wanted to verify the answer to many questions on limits of complex numbers.

So, I tried using Wolfram Alpha for the [same](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22Limit%22%2C%20%22limit%22%7D%20-%3E%221%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22Limit%22%2C%20%22limitfunction%22%7D%20-%3E%22%5B1%20-%20%28conj%28z%29%29%5D%2F%5B1-z%5D%22).

$$\lim_{z\to1}\frac{1-z^*}{1-z}$$ **does not exist.** [using path $y=m(1-x)$]

But, Wolfram Alpha computes the limit as $1$.

**Am I wrong or Wolfram Alpha does not work for complex numbers?**

Comment: Set option Direction -> Complexes to make it work properly with complex numbers.

Comment: I tried [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Limit%22%2C+%22limit%22%7D+-%3E%221%22&assumption=%7B%22FP%22%2C+%22Limit%22%2C+%22direction%22%7D+-%3E+%22Left%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Limit%22%2C+%22limitfunction%22%7D+-%3E%22%5B1-+conj%28z%29%5D%2F%281-z%29%22) Still does not work

Comment: The multivariable limit calculator works for some cases and does not work for others--the limit calculator almost never works for complex numbers...

Comment: Yep, sorry, I incorrectly assumed you're using Wolfram Mathematica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, since$$\lim_{t\to0,\,t\in\Bbb R}\frac{1-\left(\overline{t+1}\right)}{1-(t+1)}=1\quad\text{and}\quad\lim_{t\to0,\,t\in\Bbb R}\frac{1-\left(\overline{ti+1}\right)}{1-(ti+1)}=-1.$$

Comment: So, I believe I shouldn't trust Wolfram Alpha? I was computing $lim (z^2 - conj(z)^2)/z$ for z->0 using [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=2958433016861a528d6221f5ac88eefd) and it says "limit does not exist"--shouldn't the limit be 0 for this one?

Comment: Yes, that limit is $0$: I don't understand the way Wolfram Alpha deals with limits when conjugation is involved.

Answer (score 2):

Wolfram|Alpha does not always give you access to all the power of Wolfram Language/Mathematica. For this calculation, I can't find an easy way to get it to consider the limit in the complex plane.

But you can use [TryItOnline](https://tryitonline.net/) for quick non-graphical calculations like this. For example, the following code outputs `Indeterminate`, showing that the limit doesn't exist.

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/)

```
Limit[(1 - Conjugate[z])/(1 - z), z -> 1, Direction -> Complexes] // Print
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcixCoAgEADQX7kxQRF/oMXGhnZxEDnqIjXsgvDnjRrfS4E3TIEpht5nSsRuMKDAlrzfa2B0zQv9VxMSGqgRjISJKkamkj/bks4DH7w8aA1Lpcy9vw)

Answer (score 1):

Let $1-\overline z=re^{i\theta}$, then $1-z=re^{-i\theta}$, so:

$$\lim_{z\to1} \frac{1-\overline z}{1-z}=\lim_{r\to0}\frac{re^{i\theta}}{re^{-i\theta}}=\lim_{r\to0} e^{2i\theta}$$

but $\theta$ is undefined, and so the limit can tend to anything on the unit circle.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is in Maple.
[image]

The documentation specifies that if the direction is not specified, then "real bidirectional" is assumed.

Comment: Are there any online calculators available that can perform these operations? Wolfram Alpha doesn't do it I guess--I'm using it's multivariable widget to check but I think it is wrong sometimes...